# Handling comma separated values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In one of my tables i have a column which has concatenated values. The value of the column is:

```
151,225,923,920,528
```

Now i want to convert this string by putting quotes into the following format:

```
'151','225','923','920','528'
```

Since I am new to oracle i do not know functions which can help me do this. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Bad design. You must normalize your DB.

Comment: Have you tried searching for a solution before coming here? if so what have you tried to thus far?

Comment: `replace(CONCAT('''',str,''''),',',''',''')` .. Horrible to read isnt it.! Concept is single quote has to be escaped with another single quote. Replace() is very similar to the function in every high level language.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select chr(39) || replace('151,225,923,920,528',',',''',''') || chr(39) from dual
```